# How does "Multi Part" in android work

Tags: android

I want to upload video file to web-server from android but I do not know anything about multi-part in. Can somebody explain what is use of following methods?:

```
{

  conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
  conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
  conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + 
  boundary);
  conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);
  dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

 dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
 dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; 
 name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
 dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

}
```

And in

```
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

why were writing this to outstream even if it is not part of file

Comment: Why are you posting the same code twice?